# How to link IFC to Revit on Design Automation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to link an ifc into an empty Revit file using design automation. I want to be able to check the parameters of the elements of the ifc model. I managed to do it locally, I am taking the ifcname.ifc.RVT generated whit this two lines of code using Revit.IFC.Import:

```
importer importer = Importer.CreateImporter(doc, ifcFileName, options);
importer.ReferenceIFC(doc, ifcFileName, options);
```

After this I am able to open the new document generated and read the parameters with this lines:

```
var docifc = app.OpenDocumentFile(ifcFileName+".RVT");
var collector = new FilteredElementCollector(docifc).WhereElementIsNotElementType();
```

I tried to do the same using desing automation on the Autodesk platform(Autodesk Forge), creating a Temporary Upload file called Input.ifc.RVT. The problem comes after the workitem has ended successfully and the temporary upload file Input.ifc.RVT becomes an empty Revit file with 424kb, missing the ifc imported content.
I hope you have any tip to make it work or a suggestion about anything I might be missing.
Looking forward to your answers.

Using Design Automation I tried to get the ifcname.ifc.RVT generated after trying to link an IFC to be able to read the parameters of the elements in the IFC, but I am getting an empty Revit file. Do you have any clue how could I get the file with the IFC model on it?

Using Application.OpenIFCDocument Method (String) I do not get the parameters well imported so I am trying to get the linked file which contains all the parameters.

Also I tried:
var linkType = RevitLinkType.CreateFromIFC(doc, ifc_resource, linkPathRvt, true, new RevitLinkOptions(false));
But I get this error: Error: Non-optional output [Input.ifc.RVT] is missing.

I have checked this post but I am not feeling lucky:
[How to link IFC with Revit Design-Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344678/how-to-link-ifc-with-revit-design-automation)

Comment: We're sorry to hear this issue is bothering you, but could elaborate on what you did between `importer.ReferenceIFC(doc, ifcFileName, options)` and `var docifc = app.OpenDocumentFile(ifcFileName+".RVT");`? I cannot reproduce the `Input.ifc.RVT becomes an empty Revit file with 424kb` issue on my side. Here is my sample appdundle: https://github.com/yiskang/DA4R-link-Ifc-dump-props

Comment: Regarding `Using Application.OpenIFCDocument Method (String) I do not get the parameters well imported`, may I know which properties are missed? Could you share a test IFC model with me for investigation? No need to share the whole model, but just remaining the contents encountered in this issue is fine and enough.

Comment: According to our engineering team, the 3rd-argument `linkPathRvt` of the  `RevitLinkType.CreateFromIFC()` is a `*.ifc.RVT` that contains the IFC contents. In this case, we can use the result of `importer.ReferenceIFC`.